# ReferenceError: Component is not defined

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component {
    state = { advice: '' };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchAdvice();
    }

    fetchAdvice = () => {
        axios.get('https://api.adviceslip.com/advice')
            .then((response) => {
                const { advice } = response.data.slip;
                this.setState({advice});
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }

    render () {
        const { advice } = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="app">
                <div className="card">
                    <h1 className="heading">{advice}</h1>
                    <button className="button" onClick={this.fetchAdvice}>    
                        <span>Give Me Advice!</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Error :- TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in its entirety and **edit** this question based on the information on that page, to make this question appropriate for Stackoverflow. This question may be closed, if so review the how to ask page and make sure you include relevant details to help others answer you.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question. But you should define your state inside constructor.

Comment: Can you provide the component that is calling and using this `App` component?

Comment: <li>
        <Link href="#advice">
          <NavLink onClick={App}>Get an Advice</NavLink>
        </Link>
      </li>

Comment: @ArdalanNahavandi I am calling App in this component

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment, you are calling App with

```
<li> <Link href="#advice"> <NavLink onClick={App}>Get an Advice</NavLink> </Link> </li>
```

The way that you are calling App is wrong. This binds the App as a function to the event onClick. This is not the way to use a React Class Component or React Router Link.

Provide a `to` parameter value and map it to App in the Route using the Switch statement.

For reference, checkout this example
https://reactrouter.com/web/example/basic

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a react component to an `onClick` event. Or i should say to any events. You can't call components like callback functions. That's wrong. React does not support routing with URL change by itself. You should use a third party library called `react-router-dom`. Here's a link to get you started with react router. https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start